# Topaz Signature Pad in Chrome Web Application

Tags: javascript, html, topaz-signatures

I am trying to incorporate an electronic signature using the Topaz Systems signature pad into my Web Application.  Everything appears to work within Internet Explorer, as the signature pad uses Active X to access the pad plugged into the USB port.  My Web Application however is relying on Chrome so I am attempting to get this to cooperate within Chrome.

I have tried unsuccessfully to use the Active X for Chrome plugin 
[Active X for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgllffgicojgllpmdbemgglaponefajn)

The plugin itself appears to be working and there is output to the Console however I am unable to sign the box.
I am currently just trying to work with the simple demos found at 
[Topaz Site Demos](http://www.topazsystems.com/Software/download/web/index.htm)

Any help or direction as to how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried contacting support? In my experience, they've been friendly and helpful in any way that they can.

Comment: I just contacted them yesterday but figured I would hedge my bets and see if anyone else in the community had run into this issue or attempted to do this before.  I don't believe I have ever been in a situation where I am the first to do something lol.

Comment: @Brian I am facing the same issue with Topaz Signature Pad ActiveX for Firefox. Were you able to get it to work on chrome...

Comment: I wish I was able to but they offered no support for it and had no plugins for NPAPI browsers.  What I ended up doing which was a MUCH cheaper option was to buy a Wacom Bamboo Pen ($75ish), using a jquery based signature plugin and canvas element, and utilizing that for signatures.  It isn't quite as nice looking but I printed a signature piece of paper and laminated it for a guide and works pretty well for a small budget.  If you want some more details or code for how I implemented mine I would be more than happy to share it.

Comment: Hi, can you post link to this jquery based signature plugin and canvas element that works with wacom?

Comment: @Peter Im surprised I found it again but here it is from Github: https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad

Answer (score 8):

Topaz released a plugin that will work for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Internet Explorer browsers. I tested it in chrome and it works.

The following is a link to the article: 
http://www.topazsystems.com/news/SigPlusWeb.htm

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the only way to get a Topaz signature pad working in chrome is to create an applet.  Here is an example:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.beans.Beans;

import javax.comm.CommDriver;

import com.topaz.sigplus.SigPlus;
import com.topaz.sigplus.SigPlusEvent0;
import com.topaz.sigplus.SigPlusListener;


public class SigPlusAppletDemo extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        SigPlusAppletDemo demo = new SigPlusAppletDemo();
    }



    public void start() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.start();

    }



    /**
     * 
     */
    SigPlus              sigObj = null;



    public SigPlusAppletDemo()
    {


    try
        {
        ClassLoader cl = (com.topaz.sigplus.SigPlus.class).getClassLoader();
        sigObj = (SigPlus)Beans.instantiate( cl, "com.topaz.sigplus.SigPlus" );

        setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 1 ) );
        add( sigObj );


        sigObj.addSigPlusListener( new SigPlusListener()
            {
            public void handleTabletTimerEvent( SigPlusEvent0 evt )
                {
                }

            public void handleNewTabletData( SigPlusEvent0 evt )
                {
                }

            public void handleKeyPadData( SigPlusEvent0 evt )
                {
                }
            } );


        setSize( 500, 100 );
        show();

        sigObj.setTabletModel( "SignatureGemLCD1X5" );
        sigObj.setTabletComPort( "HID1" );


        sigObj.setTabletState( 1 );
        }
    catch ( Exception e )
        {
        return;
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: And for that the Apache Linux server I am running would need to support java correct?